# How to pass renderer through classes?

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl2, oop

I am making a game with SDL and C++. I am trying to render simple image to the screen but I can't. **I am not getting any error** but I see only black screen.

I think because the renderer in `player` is not the same in `game`
they do not have the same memory address.

**my question **: is how to pass the renderer?

I have tried passing it through `init()` in `player` directly but it didn't work then.

**game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class game
{
public:

    game();
    ~game();

    void init(char *title,int xpos, int ypos ,int xsize ,int ysize ,bool fullscreen);
    void loop();
    void input();
    void update();
    void render();
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Window* window;

private:

    const int target_Fps = 60;
    const float TFEF = 1000/60; // time for each frame
    int delta;
    long int start_time;
    bool isrunning = true;
    int fps_counter = 0;
    unsigned int counter = 1;
};

#endif
```

**game.cpp**

```
#include "game.h"
#include "player.h"

player* pla;

game::game()
{
    cout << "something"<<endl;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        cout << "another thing" << endl;
        init("game",10,15,500,500,false);
    }

    loop();
}

game::~game()
{
}

void game::init(char *title,int xpos, int ypos ,int xsize ,int ysize ,bool fullscreen)
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos,  ypos , xsize , ysize , fullscreen);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,0);
    //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0,0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    cout << "another another something" << endl;

    pla = new player(renderer,32,32);
    pla->init();

    //SDL_Texture* tex = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer,"res/pss.png");
}

void game::loop()
{
    while(isrunning)
    {
        start_time = SDL_GetTicks();

        input();
        update();
        render();

        delta = SDL_GetTicks() - start_time;
        if (delta < TFEF)
            SDL_Delay(TFEF - delta);

        fps_counter++;

        if (start_time >= 1000 * counter)
        {
            //cout <<"the FPS is : "<< fps_counter << endl;
            counter++;
            fps_counter = 0;
        }
    }
}

void game::input()
{
    SDL_Event e;
    SDL_PollEvent(&e);
    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        SDL_Quit();
}

void game::update(){}

void game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    pla->render(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

gameobject::~gameobject(){};
```

**player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "gameobject.h"

class gameobject;

class player : public gameobject
{
public:

    void init() override;
    void tick() override;
    void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer) override;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    player(SDL_Renderer* renderer,int pwidth,int pheight);
private:

    ~player() override;
    SDL_Texture* playertex;
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include "player.h"

player::player(SDL_Renderer* renderer,int pwidth, int pheight)
{
   this->pos.w = pwidth;
   this->pos.h = pheight;
   this->pos.x = 0;
   this->pos.y = 0;

   this->renderer = renderer;
}

void player::init()
{
    this->playertex= IMG_LoadTexture(renderer,"res/pss.png");
    cout<<"int in player \n"<<endl;

    crop.x = 0;
    crop.y = 0;
    crop.w = 32;
    crop.h = 32;

    cout<<"pos x :"<<this->pos.x<<endl;
    cout<<"pos y : "<<this->pos.y<<endl;
    cout<<"pos w : "<<this->pos.w<<endl;
    cout<<"pos h : "<<this->pos.h<<endl;
    cout<<"crop x :"<<this->crop.x<<endl;
    cout<<"crop y :"<<this->crop.y<<endl;
    cout<<"crop w :"<<this->crop.w<<endl;
    cout<<"crop h : "<<this->crop.h<<endl;
}

void player::tick()
{
}

void player::render(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
/*
    cout<<"pos x :"<<this->pos.x<<endl;
    cout<<"pos y : "<<this->pos.y<<endl;
    cout<<"pos w : "<<this->pos.w<<endl;
    cout<<"pos h : "<<this->pos.h<<endl;
    cout<<"crop x :"<<this->crop.x<<endl;
    cout<<"crop y :"<<this->crop.y<<endl;
    cout<<"crop w :"<<this->crop.w<<endl;
    cout<<"crop h : "<<this->crop.h<<endl;
*/
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,playertex,&crop,&pos);
}

player::~player(){};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ SDL2 : can't load textures to the game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176989/c-sdl2-cant-load-textures-to-the-game)

Comment: no that was another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at C++ language concepts, such as passing by reference, address, and value.

If I have a class, Foo, and another, Bar:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    int num;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void doSomethingV(Bar bar);
    void doSomethingR(Bar& bar);
    void doSomethingA(Bar* bar);
};
```

Look at the `doSomething*` member functions: the first one passes the object *by value*, which means inside the function, a copy (new instance) is made of the Bar object. Typically we do not do this.

The second version is passing *by reference*. This is basically a pointer, but it has the extra safety of not allowing null values:

```
foo.doSomethingR(NULL); //generates a compiler error
foo.doSomethingR(bar); //works, as long as bar is an instance of an object(not pointer)
```

Do this when you can. Function definitions can treat the variable as an instance of an object instead of a pointer, but what really gets passed is the address of the object.

The final version, is passing *by address*, or pointer. As above, the calling convention is as follows:

```
foo.doSomethingA(NULL); //valid
foo.soSomethingA(&bar); //valid. '&' means "address of"
```

Use this when you have to.

Now to your case:

If you wish to *store* a copy of the renderer, then pass by value, or reference. Preferably reference.

If you wish to *use* the renderer, pass by reference only.

If you wish to store the address of the renderer, pass by pointer, or reference;

If you pass by pointer, your storing class must have a pointer member variable to receive the address like `Renderer* m_renderer;` which is then assigned like so:

```
player::player(SDL_Renderer* renderer,int pwidth, int pheight)
{
    pos.w = pwidth;
    pos.h = pheight;
    pos.x = 0;
    pos.y = 0;
    m_renderer = renderer;
}
```

If you pass by reference:

```
player::player(SDL_Renderer& renderer,int pwidth, int pheight)
{
    pos.w = pwidth;
    pos.h = pheight;
    pos.x = 0;
    pos.y = 0;
    m_renderer = &renderer;
}
```

Also, as a side note: the keyword `this` is only necessary when the argument name is the same as the member variable, which is whilst syntactically correct, considered poor practice. See my examples above for a better way to do it. Another use for `this` is when a class instance wishes to pass itself as an argument, like so:

```
Bar::doSomething(Foo& foo)
{
    foo.doSomethingA(this); //passes itself by pointer
    foo.doSomethingR(*this); //pass itself by reference. 
    // '*' is opposite of '&' operator and is called de-referencing a pointer
}
```

Comment: still didn't work this is my code 
**they didn't let me to paste it here so i will just do it on paste online website**https://pastebin.com/MLL6jrbb

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to debug your own code. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions. explore the concepts I described, until you understand them completely, then you should be able to solve your own problem. If not, you will be able to ask a more detailed, and specific question.

Comment: iask a detailed about my code 
i tried what u said but nothing

Comment: You asked about passing an object to another object: " **my question ** : is how to pass the renderer " ,which I answered.

If that did not solve your problem, then update your question with what you have tried, and try to be more specific about what you want help with.

Comment: now its the same memory-adress but still doesn't render

Comment: As I said, I cannot debug your code for you. My advice to you would be, instead of muddying the waters with things like inheritance, create a functional, minimal complete program, to learn and understand the SDL2 API, then incorporate it into your main program.

Comment: the SDL API is not a problem 
and i solve the problem 
thank you sir

Comment: That's great to hear. If you know what the problem is, then post an answer to your own question, so others can benefit too.

Comment: the answer is u 
thank you so much